# Solving a least squares problem with linear constraints in Python

Tags: optimization, python, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I need to solve

\begin{alignat}{1}
& \min_{x}\|Ax - b\|^2_{2}, \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & \quad\sum_{i}x_{i} = 1, \\
& \quad x_{i} \geq 0, \quad \forall{i}. 
\end{alignat}

I **think** it is a quadratic problem which should be solvable with [CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/), but I can't work out how.

Comment: I hope this question is not too specific for compsci.

Comment: Geoff Oxberry: Just a curiosity, but why did you edit out the linear-part? I think it is quite a impotent part of the problem description, the solution would be quite different for a non-linear least squares optimization.

Comment: Btw, the other edits are great!

Comment: You can easily solve this by your own code in very efficient way. No need for CVXOPT.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote a full answer (below the line) before discovering [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org), which (like CVX for MATLAB) does all the hard stuff for you and has a very short example almost identical to yours [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~ttinoco/cvxpy/overview.html).  You only need to replace the relevant line with

```
 p = program(minimize(norm2(A*x-b)),[equals(sum(x),1),geq(x,0)])
```

---

My old answer, doing it the harder way with CVXOPT:

Following Geoff's suggestion to square your objective function gives

$$\|Ax-b\|^2_2 = \langle x^TA^T - b^T,Ax-b\rangle = x^TA^TAx - b^TAx - x^TAb - b^Tb$$

Of course, all terms are scalars, so you can transpose the third one and drop the last one (as it doesn't depend on $x$ and therefore won't change which $x$ gives you a minimum, though you will need to add it back in after solving in order to get the correct value of your objective) to obtain
$$ x^TA^TAx - b^T(A + A^T)x$$
This (including your constraints) has the form of a quadratic program, as given in the CVXOPT documentation [here](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming), where there is also example code for solving such a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the problem you solved, solve

\begin{alignat}{1}
& \min_{x}\|Ax - b\|^{2}_{2}, \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & \quad\sum_{i}x_{i} = 1, \\
& \quad x_{i} \geq 0, \quad \forall{i}. 
\end{alignat}

This problem is a differentiable, convex, nonlinear optimization problem that can be solved in CVXOPT, IPOPT, or any other convex optimization solver.